# Laravel 7 run queue:listen from route on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am wondering how to run `php artisan queue:listen database` manually to execute a job on a shared hosting. I am trying it from route file web.php :

```
Route::get('/job', function () {
    Artisan::call('queue:listen');
    return 'Job Started....';
});
```

Another approach I tried with cron job in cPanel:

```
/usr/local/bin/php/home2/courage/project_folder/artisan queue:listen database --daemon
```

But both the approach is not working. **I am able to run the job from local.** How can I achieve this??

Comment: You have SSH access? Then you can run `php artisan queue:listen database --daemon`

Comment: No i dont have. thats why struggling. :(

Comment: You can create cronjobs? Then create a cronjob like this `/usr/local/php73/bin/php artisan queue:listen database --daemon`

Comment: I do not know how to create cron jobs. can you put some light on this?

Comment: Normally you can create cronjobs in the webhost control panel like Plesk or DirectAdmin

Comment: Most shared hosts will not permit a long-running command like `queue:listen`.

Comment: It is a bad idea to run laravel app on shared hosting. You will be limited by their services.

Comment: This can help you https://www.google.com/amp/s/laravelarticle.com/amp/laravel-scheduler-on-cpanel-shared-hosting

Comment: @DeepeshThapa tried this but not working. Can you assist me?

Comment: @WahidSheriefcan you elaborate  what is not working in the link above

Comment: @bhucho i updated the question. have a look kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel `queue:[listen|work]` is a long-running background task. Once it starts, unless you send a quit/terminate signal, it runs for the lifetime. On the other hand, all the HTTP calls have timeouts. So, if you call an HTTP endpoint, if your application (can be of any technology stack), will timeout after a certain period of time (generally 30s).

So, in theory, yes. In your HTTP endpoint, you can run the command using the `Artisan` facade, but it'll stop working after it hits the t/o.

Secondly, your cron. Crons are supposed to work in a periodic manner. Suppose you want to transfer your logs from your server to another server after 5 mins, in those cases, you can run crons. Crons are like schedule jobs. So practically, crons don't have any effect in your case as well.

Finally, in shared hosting, you can only serve HTTP req-res only, unless the provider provides you the ssh access. As others said in the comments, you can't use the full functionality of Laravel in shared hosting. You need to move from shared hosting to any VPS.

Comment: Also, running artisan command via HTTP is a bad idea

Comment: that's why I mentioned in theory.

Comment: well explained @ssi-anik to the point and very informative.